# How to use submit's action when page address is set like this "http://onigra.net/cp2/index.php?page=default"?

Tags: php, button, get

I am totally new to PHP, just one of my friends asked to modify his site and I trying to do this, since he think programmers can do everything.

I needed to create text field and button, then insert something into database after button is pressed.

I done it that by creating a form like that in default.php:

```
<form action = 'default.php' method = 'get'>
    <input type = 'text' id = 'txt_teacher_name' name = 'txt_teacher_name' />
    <input type = 'submit' value = 'Set' />
</form>
```

And this code is loaded in page when address bar have this address: `http://onigra.net/cp2/index.php?page=default`

After pressing the button address changes to this: `http://onigra.net/cp2/default.php?txt_teacher_name=zxc` and I getting 404 error.

What I need to do to make submit this form and stay on same page?

Comment: show some code in index.php,, and in which file is this form at?

Comment: The code is in `default.php`. Other peoples already answered without need of `index.php` code, so it's not needed anymore. Thank you for paying attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need change to your source like this

```
<form action = 'index.php' method = 'get'>
    <input type = 'text' id = 'txt_teacher_name' name = 'txt_teacher_name' />
    <input type = 'hidden' name = 'page' value = 'default' />
    <input type = 'submit' value = 'Set' />
</form>
```

Your url should be `http://onigra.net/cp2/index.php?page=default&txt_teacher_name=foo`

Answer (score 1):

index.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET(txt_teacher_name)) {
    //do db insert
}
?>

<form action = 'index.php' method = 'get'>
    <input type = 'text' id = 'txt_teacher_name' name = 'txt_teacher_name' />
    <input type = 'submit' value = 'Set' />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you too, but I can't accept both answers. `Quỳnh Nguyễn` were first, so I giving best answer to him.